# Jenkins - Option to have all jenkinsfiles put in one separate folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am planning to create a Project in Jenkins and I am thinking of using Organisation folder for that.
Since the project has severals applications (mobile app with backend and frontend parts) I have several repos that will need to be separate jobs.

My question here is is it possible (or is it a good/bad practice as well) to put all Jenkinsfiles for all the apps in one separate folder (called Jenkinsfiles for example) from where I will invoke the corresponding file?

Until now I have been placing Jenkinsfile in the repo where is my app that I am doing the build but now, with whole project, I need to decide which approach to take so I would appreshiate any contribution in decision making

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking "can it be done" the answer is Yes, most likely - but how will you manage which Jenkinsfile is being run?

As I see it, the main idea is to have the Jenkinsfile next to the code being deployed.

If you have several applications in your project repository, maybe you could have separate repositories with "just" the Jenkinsfile and deployment config. You could then use the Jenkinsfile in the main code repo to trigger all the sub-jobs.

I have done something similar, and have seen several companies with separate jobs for prod/user-test that require separate permissions to be triggered as well

Comment: so, would the best practice be to put Jenkinsfiles in corresponding folder? We were considering one folder for all Jenkinsfiles to reduce writing rights for devops for the folders that are in the scope of developers. The option of having multiple folders for each jenkinsfile, wouldn't it create a crowd in the project repo?

Comment: I would put each jenkinsfile, and any config in a separate repo - that way you also have a cleaner log of the changes for that build  job. otherwise you would have to have very separate setups when setting up your jenkins build jobs

Comment: when you say in separate repo, do you mean like one repo for all jenkinsfiles or one repo per jenkinsfile er app?

Comment: one repo per jenkinsfile